# How to shorten the timezone name list from moment.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm using the moment.js library to get a list of time zone names via moment.tz.names(). But this query returns a list of 500+ options, which is a lot. Is there some alternative way to get a short list? I couldn't find the answer in the documentation.

Comment: I recommend not using Moment.js anyway. Look for dayjs or alike. Otherwise, you can always use a slice method to shorten the collection.

Comment: Depends on what timezones are relevant for you.

Comment: I want to leave only the most popular, no more than 100.

Comment: i want to leave all timezones but no more than 100